# How to calculate $\prod_{x=2}^\infty\frac x{(\ln x)^x}$

Tags: approximation, infinite-product

$$\prod_{x=2}^\infty\frac x{(\ln x)^x}$$
I tried checking the answer at Wolfram Alpha, and it gave me the answer $≈0.×10^{-100}$.

Does the denominator of $(\ln x)^x$ make it so large that the product tends to zero?

How to actually evaluate it, or at least how to find a nice approximation?

Comment: Note that $x^y=e^{y\cdot ln(x)}$. Thus your denominator $ln^x(x)$ is equal to $e^{x\cdot ln(ln(x))}$. Yeah, it grows quite fast. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x>e^e$ you have $\log x>e$ and $\log^x x>e^x$ so the sequence $\frac{x}{\log^x x}\to 0$, and thus the product is zero.